# How to query wires that are connected to selected component in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I want to apply special rule only to components with myFootprint and all connected wires to it.

AD can select all components with that footprint with this query [HasFootprint](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/Query_Lang-PCBFunctions_MembershipChecks_HasFootprint((HasFootprint))_AD)('myFootprint').

I also know that it can select and query out all wires with [IsWire](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/Query_Lang-PCBFunctions_AttributeChecks_IsWire((IsWire))_AD) but the question is about filtering-out just connected wires to queried component?

Comment: meeting point here is probably that Net of Wire is the same as Net of (one of) pad in component.

Comment: Even if this can be done, it will probably be quicker to just go back to the schematic and put a blanket with a net class rule on all the wires connected to the component. Or if you're trying to do something like fan out from a BGA, put a region around the part.

Comment: One of workaround is also to create room and select elements into room with query IsTrack (and all you want) than use [WithinRoom](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/Query_Lang-PCBFunctions_MembershipChecks_WithinRoom((WithinRoom))_AD) to apply rule on it.

Answer (score 1):

May be one of this helps:

For rules like track min with:

Open Project options -> Class Generation and enable "Generate Net Class for Components".
After you did sync this to your PCB you can define a design rule (e.g. track min with) valid for all nets which are connected to e.g. IC123. But you Design rule will get quite unmanageable as you need to define either many rules or one rule with many "OR" (... OR IC123 OR IC456 OR IC789...) AND you will run into troubles when annotating changes the IC Designator

e.g. for clearance rules:

In the schematic: add a parameter name "ClassName" value "exclude_8mm_clearance" to every IC you want the clearance rule be applied. This will add this devices to the component class "exclude_8mm_clearance" In the PCB design rules add "NOT InComponentClass('exclude_8mm_clearance')" to your design rule to avoid DRC clearance errors for this specific Items.